# Error generate new block with signet test

Tags: bitcoin-core, signet

I have tried to test signet to generate new block but it is showed message as below:

bicoin-cli -signet -generate 1

```
ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: AcceptBlock FAILED (bad-signet-blksig, signet block signature validation failure)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create blocks yourself for the global signet; it requires signatures by the parties running that signet.

You can create your own signet, though, where you yourself are the signer. The tooling around this is still a work in progress, as far as I know.